# Reading UTC time strings

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I'm trying to read some UTC data strings using moments.js.

e.g.

```
date1 = moment.utc("160114224512Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(date1)
```

However, this always throws an invalid date error

Comment: That should throw a syntax error instead.

Comment: no I get "Invalid date"

Comment: With that *exact* code? Unless you're using some kind of preparser I very much doubt it; `160114224512Z` is a syntax error.

Comment: No, definitely syntax error. I expect you really have quotes around it, e.g. `moment.utc("160114224512Z")...` But as you've put it in your question, that's a syntax error.

Comment: Yes updated missing quotes to reflect real code.

Answer (score 1):

Moment will accept unix timestamps in both seconds and milliseconds as strings, if you specify the `x` or `X` token. You actually don't even need to strip the Z - the regular expression related to the `x` and `X` tokens is looking for a number, so it will ignore the Z by default.

I think you have milliseconds there, so you would use the small `x` token, as follows:

```
moment.utc("160114224512Z", 'x').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
"1975-01-28 04:10:24"
```

That look right?

As an additional note, it might be *good* to strip the Z for purposes of clarity, even if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have quotes you haven't shown, e.g.:

```
date1 = moment.utc("160114224512Z").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// Note -----------^-------------^
console.log(date1)
```

The problem is simple: That isn't a valid date/time string, in any format I've ever seen. It's certainly not ISO-8601, for instance.

It *looks* like a seconds-since-the-Epoch value for Jan 28th, 1975, since it's just a number and it's too big to be milliseconds-since-the-Epoch (unless you really have a date in the year 7043).

If it's seconds-since-the-epoch, ditch the `Z` and use it as a number:

```
date1 = moment.utc(160114224512).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

The string `160114224512Z` is not a valid UTC moment format, nor a valid moment format.

I would advise you to specify your input format, I'd do:

`moment.utc(160114224512, 'x').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`